# How do I pass access token in an API call using the Intuit-Oauth node library?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to make and API call to a QuickBooks endpoint from my express app, but I keep getting the following error:

> "Missing required parameter: access_token"

I checked the Intuit documentation and it said the following:

> Access tokens let your app connect and send requests to our APIs.
> Pass the access_token value in the authorization header of every API request your app makes. The value should always be: Authorization: Bearer {AccessToken}

So what I've done is tried to extract the access token, then pass it into my API call:

```
app.get("/callback", function (req, res) {
  console.log('it got here')
  oauthClient
    .createToken(req.url)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
      const newToken = JSON.parse(oauth2_token_json)
      access_token = newToken.access_token    **TOKEN EXTRACTED HERE**
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/companyInfo" );

});
```

```
app.get("/getCompanyInfo", (req, res) => {
  let companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;

  let url = oauthClient.environment == "sandbox" ? OAuthClient.environment.sandbox : OAuthClient.environment.production;


  oauthClient
    .makeApiCall({
      url: url + "v3/company/" + companyID + "/companyinfo/" + companyID,
      headers:{
        'Authorization':{
         'Bearer': access_token  //**PASSED INTO API CALL HERE**
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      console.log(
        "The response for API call is :" + JSON.stringify(authResponse)
      );
      res.send(JSON.parse(authResponse.text()));
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
});
```

..however it's still not working. This part of OAuth authorization is still confusing me - any suggestions on how to make this work?

Here's the whole express part of the app:

```
const express = require("express");
const OAuthClient = require("intuit-oauth");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require('axios')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
let oauth2_token_json = null;
let access_token = null;
let oauthClient = null;

app.get("/authUri", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
    clientId: "******",
    clientSecret: "******",
    environment: "sandbox",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3001/callback",
  });
  let authUri = oauthClient.authorizeUri({
    scope: [OAuthClient.scopes.Accounting],
    state: "testState",
  });
  res.send(authUri);
});

app.get("/callback", function (req, res) {
  console.log('it got here')
  oauthClient
    .createToken(req.url)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
      const newToken = JSON.parse(oauth2_token_json)
      access_token = newToken.access_token
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/companyInfo" );

});

app.get("/getCompanyInfo", (req, res) => {
  let companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;

  let url = oauthClient.environment == "sandbox" ? OAuthClient.environment.sandbox : OAuthClient.environment.production;


  oauthClient
    .makeApiCall({
      url: url + "v3/company/" + companyID + "/companyinfo/" + companyID,
      headers:{
        'Authorization':{
         'Bearer': access_token
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      console.log(
        "The response for API call is :" + JSON.stringify(authResponse)
      );
      res.send(JSON.parse(authResponse.text()));
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello from server");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was putting my `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` in the body instead of header. Yet your issue is related to notation, thus use Bearer as a string value instead of key/field as you tried:

```
app.get("/getCompanyInfo", (req, res) => {
  let companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;

  let url = oauthClient.environment == "sandbox" ? OAuthClient.environment.sandbox : OAuthClient.environment.production;


  oauthClient
    .makeApiCall({
      url: url + "v3/company/" + companyID + "/companyinfo/" + companyID,
      headers:{
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + access_token //**PASSED INTO API CALL HERE**
      }
    })
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      console.log(
        "The response for API call is :" + JSON.stringify(authResponse)
      );
      res.send(JSON.parse(authResponse.text()));
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
});
```